# LWC table my custom object and combobox picklist filtred

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, picklist, lightning-combobox

I have a task to display a table of positions with the status field Combobox Picklist filtred.
As I have not experience in JS and LWC, it is so difficult for me to understand how to do this.
Help me please.

**My controller:**

```
public with sharing class PositionControllerLWC {
    
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
        public static List<Position__c> getListPositions(String filter) {
            if (filter.equals('All')) {
                return [SELECT Name, Status__c, Skills__c, Open_Date__c, Min_Rate__c, Max_Rate__c, Company__c
                FROM Position__c];
            } else {
                return [SELECT Name, Status__c, Skills__c, Open_Date__c, Min_Rate__c, Max_Rate__c, Company__c
                FROM Position__c WHERE Status__c = :filter];
            }
        }
    }
```

**JS code:**

```
import {LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import getListPositions from '@salesforce/apex/PositionControllerLWC.getListPositions';
import POSITION_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Position__c';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Position__c.Status__c';

export default class PositionComponent extends LightningElement {

    @track isTypeSelected = true;
    @track typeSelected;
    @track resultPosition = [];
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: POSITION_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get positionObjectCheck() {
        if (this.objectInfo.data) {
            return this.objectInfo.data.fields;
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD })
    typePicklistValues;

    handleChange(event) {
        this.typeSelected = event.detail.value;
        this.isTypeSelected = false;
    }

    async getResultPosition() {
    let listOfPositions = await getListPositions({filter: this.typeSelected});
    listOfPositions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listOfPositions));
    const positions = [];
    listOfPositions.forEach(pos => positions.push({item: pos, initialStatus: pos.Status__c}));
    return positions;
    }

    async connectedCallback() {
        this.resultPosition = await this.getResultPosition();
    }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<template>
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
    <thead>
    <lightning-card title="Select Status">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={typePicklistValues.data}>
                <lightning-combobox class=""
                                    options={typePicklistValues.data.values}
                                    dropdown-alignment="auto"
                                    label="Status"
                                    placeholder="--Select Status--"
                                    value={typeSelected}
                                    onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-combobox>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <template if:true={resultPosition}>
        <template for:each={resultPosition} for:item="pos">
            <tr class="slds-truncate" key={pos.item.Id}>
                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Name}>
                    <td data-label="Position name">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Position name">{pos.item.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Status__c}>
                    <td data-label="Status">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">{pos.item.Status__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Skills__c}>
                    <td data-label="Skills">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Skills">{pos.item.Skills__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Open_Date__c}>
                    <td data-label="Open Date">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Open Date">{pos.item.Open_Date__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Min_Rate__c}>
                    <td data-label="Min Rate">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Min Rate">{pos.item.Min_Rate__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Max_Rate__c}>
                    <td data-label="Max Rate">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Max Rate">{pos.item.Max_Rate__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <template if:true={positionObjectCheck.Company__c}>
                    <td data-label="Company">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Company">{pos.item.Company__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What is your specific question? Please [edit] your post to clarify. See [ask].

Comment: Are you getting any particular errors? I think you are not far off - your code looks well thought out and nicely formatted. Check that the wire service can handle the reactive parameter you are using `$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId`. If not, you could use a getter for that - and if that fails (unlikely) you could use a wire service method handler